# My refrigerator is not efficiently cooling

Tags: refrigerator

I have a problem with my twin door refrigerator,

first its not cooling properly the freezer side is not freezing as required.

secondly there is red sign that's coming in the dash of the refrigerator, kindly help if anyone knows about this issue.

i don't know if the temperature is correct.[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site @john. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a malfunctioning appliance rather than cooking - it's just not the sort of question we answer. A red exclamation mark is generally a sign the fridge is busted and needs a technician. It could be any number of things (compressor, heat exchanger, pump, fan), you'll need to call a specialist to be sure.

Comment: @GdD  : How is this question all that different from asking how to deal with problematic seasoning on a cast iron pan?  Something went wrong, and they want to know how to fix it

Comment: Around the back of the fridge there's a little DRIP TUBE, make sure it is not clogged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John, you might want to find the manual for the fridge, and see if there's some way to get a trouble code.  You can often find them online these days ... even for older appliances.

It's possible that with everything computerized, you might have to do something before display a code, but in previous decades, there'd be a light that blinked with a given pattern, or multiple lights in a pattern, and you'd compare it to a table in the manual.  I would try to find one on the manufacturer's websites, although there are some sites that specialize in just manuals.**

It might be something as simple as needing to clean some cooling fins or coils, or just making sure they have proper airflow.  It's possible that they've gone the way of modern cars, where you have to connect a device to read the code ... in which case, the cost might be high enough to check the code that it'd be better to just  get a repair person in to take a look at it.

** But there have also been groups putting up PDFs with exploit code in them ... they take legitimate stuff from other sites and use them as trojan horses.  I haven't heard of it happening with repair manuals, but I'd make sure your virus scanning software is running and up-to-date before downloading PDFs from just anywhere.

Comment: I'm surprised by the downvote ... did my mentioning the possibility of PDF trojan horses qualify as 'health information'?  Or do you just not like that there are questions about appliances on here?  We have other questions about maintaining cooking equipment on here.